# Merging image and gif with javascript (discord)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Is there any way for my node.js app to combine PNG and a GIF into one file, one as the foreground, second as the background, and then output it?

Comment: You might have to use ffmpeg or another image manipulation program. Here is an example: [_"Overlay animated images with transparency over a static background image using ffmpeg?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10507897/1762224)

Comment: is there any way to integrate FFmpeg into js, or can you just do it with commands in the command line?

Comment: You may want to look into the [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) or [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) libraries.